# how to map uppercase column name on spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

This is my mysql column

```
staffGroup  varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci
```

This is my entity mapping

```
@Column(name = "staffGroup")
private String staffGroup;
```

This is my criteria

```
public List<Staff> getStaff() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (List<Staff>) session.createCriteria(Staff.class).list();
}
```

hibernate show this error message

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'this_.staff_group' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure your column in the database is `staffGroup` and not `staff_group`?

Comment: @zero01alpha I am sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```